# Using .then in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to fetch data set an assign them to a list. The data set is fetching but after assigning it displays this,
[Instance of 'DataAddOn', Instance of 'DataAddOn', Instance of 'DataAddOn', Instance of 'DataAddOn', Instance of 'DataAddOn']

```
void initState() {
    accountHandler.fetchDataAddOns().then((data) {
      setState(() {
        filteredList = data;
        items = data;
        print(filteredList[1].validity);
        if (items == null) {
          print("NULL");
        } else {
          print(items);
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

The print command simply does not print the content of that data type. You can either debug and expand the filteredList items, or you need to further specify the print result aka filteredList[1].validity.whatever

Answer (score 0):

```
print(items);
```

above line is actually printing a list of some instance. You can't print any dart object directly using the `print()` method. You can convert each object to a json object or something then you can print using `print()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `DataAddOn.toString()`, and print it whatever way you want it printed.